# How does a character creator system works?

Tags: skeletal-animation, character

Like in Aion for example, how does it work?

Do I just need to take a basic 3D mesh of a character I created and then make some modifications to it with sliders or do I need to create different clone meshes?

Is a system like that hard to create? If it is just long and tedious work no problem I have time, but my skills are limited so I don't know if I'm able to make such a system at all.

Also what kind of scripts and programs are best to start and make some prototypes and training? Are there some that aren't compatible with others?

Comment: Take a look at skeletal animation. Add bones to vertices (for example one bone for the nose) and transform that bone according to a slider. Scale the bone up and the vertices will follow, making the nose bigger.

Comment: wow  is it  really that easy  ?  Thanks !